# Use PHP mimic web browser post form submission? Not cURL

Tags: php, javascript, browser, post, curl

I know how to submit post submissions by cURL - preparing all the variables (name & value pairs) and then submit. But what I want to do here is to mimic a real use click of the submit button.

So I use cURL to navigate to the web page that carries the ..., and then click "Submit" button. All the hidden variables in  are then automatically submitted as is. I don't have to prepare all the hidden variables manually as I would do in a normal cURL request.

Any idea? May be in combination with some JavaScript to mimic a browser?

Comment: what is your use case? you can look at something like Selenium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be much easier to just parse the HTML of the page and get all input elements, and then use cURL to make the request.

Mimicking a browser is not trivial.

Comment: Agreed. cURL has support for mimicking any UA you care to choose. Don't rewrite the wheel.